# Ubuntu / Gnome window resizing horizontally

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, window

The Gnome programmers probably have a hidden counter of each time a user misses the resize of a window horizontally, and take a good laugh when they look at it...

Because to resize a window horizontally, one need to click **exactly** on the very pixel at the edge of the window (on the left, or on the right).

I feel the pain of the users having those old roller ball mouses...

Anyway, is there a way to configure this?
Meaning, is there a way to change the width of the area that makes the mouse pointer feels it should change into the *resize* mode?

Comment: Not sure if this works in Gnome, but sometimes in linux, you can hold `alt` and right click.  This will resize windows from anywhere in the window.

Comment: Alt-right-click opens the right click menu... that allows a resize! Too bad you didn't post an answer :-)

Comment: Made into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use gnome, so I couldn't remember if this applies.  But, when I hold `alt` and right click, it resizes the window.

@ring0 replied to my comment adding that in gnome, it brings up a menu with 'resize' being an option.  Once he mentioned that, I remembered that this was one of the many reasons I don't like gnome.  I really like my alt-right-click resize...

Comment: It works actually!

Answer (score 1):

It's defined by the Metacity theme. Find a theme that has a wider border.

Or just use Alt-Middle Click.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to customize *only* the width of the border left & right? I.e. without changing the theme...

Comment: You could modify the theme metadata; no clue if that counts as "changing" it.